# Set element inside array of array

Tags: php

If the 3rd element of array inside cars array is true i want to set others to be true .How to achieve it?

```
<?php 
  $cars = array
          (
          array(1,1,'f'),
          array(2,2,'f'),
          array(3,3,'t'),
          array(4,4,'f')
          );

        foreach($cars as $keys){
            if($keys[2]=='t')
           $count=1;
       }

        foreach($cars as $keys){
          if($count==1)
             $keys[2] = 't';
        }
        print_r($cars);
   ?>
```

Comment: Why do you use a string named "f" and a strnig named "t" instead of the boolean values true and false?

Comment: f and t were strings there not boolean types @Xatenev

Comment: Exactly, the question is *why* you use `'f'` and `'t'` instead of `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change 2 things as described below, Try:

```
$cars = array
  (
  array(1,1,'f'),
  array(2,2,'f'),
  array(3,3,'t'),
  array(4,4,'f')
  );
$count = 0; // declare $count
foreach($cars as $keys){
    if($keys[2]=='t')
        $count=1;
}
foreach($cars as $key=>$keys){
  if($count==1)
     $cars[$key][2] = 't'; // change value to t like this
}
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => t
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => t
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 3
            [2] => t
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 4
            [2] => t
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost close, Just make this change, use reference symbol `&` to actual change

from

```
foreach($cars as $keys){
```

to

```
foreach($cars as &$keys){
```

Check this : https://eval.in/609879

Answer (score 1):

```
$exists= false;
foreach($cars as $car)
{
    if($car[2] == 't')
    {
        $exists= true;
    }
}

if($exists)
{
    for($i=0; $i<count($cars); $i++)
    {
        $cars[$i][2] = 't';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution for you

```
<?php

$cars = array(
    array(1,1,'f'),
    array(2,2,'f'),
    array(3,3,'t'),
    array(4,4,'f')
);

if(in_array('t', array_column($cars, 2))){
    $cars = array_map(function($v){
        $v[2] = 't';
        return $v;
    }, $cars);
}
```